# In iOS ARC my recursive function crashes application with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

Following code of mine generates crash in ARC mode:

`MxTextField.m`

```
+enableAllTextFields:(BOOL)enable InViews:(__weak UIView*) view
{

   @try
   {
      NSArray* textFields = view.subViews;

      for(int idx = 0; idx < textFields.count; idx++)
      {
         __weak UIView* view = [textFields objectAtIndex:idx];

         if(view.subViews.count > 0)
            [MxTextField enableAllTextFields:enable InView:view];
         else
            NSLog(@"No SubViews");

         if([view class] == [MxTextField class])
            [(MxTextField*) view setEnabled:enable];
      }

   }
   @catch(NSException exception)
   {
      NSLog(@"%s : %@",__func__,exception);
   }

}
```

After Some Loop on the execution of this function It crashes by showing breakpoint at the end of the function saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Can anyone help me out that what goes wrong in this implementation?

Any help will be thankful.

Comment: try/catch is rarely a good idea.  Start by removing that.  And rather than compare the class you should use `if ([view isKindOfClass:[MxTextField class]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside many other problems the only reason for a crash that I can see from the posted code is that your method is supposed to return an object but does not do so.

Explanation: While it's not common to leave out the return type in Objective-C it's perfectly legal. It means that the method returns an object of type id.

Since your method lacks a return statement the returned value is undefined. This confuses ARC and probably makes it autorelease the random value in the return register which, eventually, leads to the crash.

Here's a proper version of your method:

```
+ (void)forAllTextFieldsIn:(UIView *)view setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[MxTextField class]])
        [(MxTextField *)view setEnabled:enabled];

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
        [self forAllTextFieldsIn:subview setEnabled:enabled];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be the method adopted for iteration and also try-catch is not a good practice, use fast-enumeration for faster and reliable result . The below code could resolve your problem

```
+(void)enableAllTextField:(BOOL)enable inView:(UIView *)contrainerView
{
    for (UIView *subview in contrainerView.subviews) {
        if(subview.subviews.count>0)
             [MxTextField enableAllTextField:enable inView:subview];
        else if ([subview isKindOfClass:[MxTextField class]]) {
             MxTextField *textField = (MxTextField *)subview;
             [textField setEnabled:enable];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, can an MXTextField have subviews?

Comment: @Paulw11 : MSTextField is a customised class and it depends upon the implementation whether it could have subview or not .

Comment: Exactly, the original code examined subviews for both MxTextField and non-MxTextField objects - yours does not.  I suspect that it isn't likely that a (presumably) UITextField subclass will have further `MxTextFields` as subviews, but it is something for the OP to be aware of

Comment: @Paulw11 : Thanks Paul , considering your query I have edited my anywer fulfilling the requirement

Comment: Still not quite. It should be two `if`s - no else.

Comment: @Paulw11 It's up to the developer to compose the view hierarchy so it's obviously correct not to leave out any views when descending into the hierarchy.

Comment: @Paulw11 : With due respect to your comments , I would like say that removing "else" the would be a big blunder with the efficiency of code .  Also currently it is handling the case you are talking about .

Comment: I agree on efficiency and your original and current versions are probably fine, but they don't do exactly the same thing as the OPs code.  With the else there an MxTextField that contains subviews (i.e. subview.count >0) won't get enabled because of the else